# Wordpress menu to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have wordpress installed on my server and I have another script in the server but another directory. How can I add the wordpress menu to my script page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Simple HTML DOM you would do something like the following:

```
<?php    
    $html = str_get_html("YOUR WORDPRESS SITE URL");
    $elem = $html->find('div[id=wrapper_content]', 0);//wrapper_content is you wordpress menu id    
    //right
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents
    preg_match($s_searchFor, $file_contents, $matches); //match the element
    $file_contents = $matches[0]; //set the file_contents var to the matched elements
?>
```

Put this code were you have created menu for your script. This will get your wordpress menu in `$file_contents` variable and `echo $file_contents;` where your menu should be.